# Simple question about stationary sets in transitive models of ZFC

Tags: set-theory

Let $\kappa$ be a regular cardinal, and suppose $X\subseteq\kappa$ is stationary in $\kappa$. Furthermore, let $\mathcal{M}$ be a transitive class model of ZFC with $X\in\mathcal{M}$. I'm trying to show that $X$ is stationary in $\kappa$ in $\mathcal{M}$. While this seems to follow pretty straightforwardly from some basic absoluteness results for such models, I'm still somewhat new to this stuff and so don't understand what it actually takes to prove such a claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the statement "$X$ is stationary", how does it look like?

"For every normal function $f\colon\kappa\to\kappa$ there is some $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=x$".

Saying that $f$ is a normal function is a $\Delta_0$ statement, and there is $x\in X$ is a $\Delta_0$ if we allow $X$ as a parameter. So all in all this is a $\Pi_1$ statement with a parameter: $X$.

Now use absoluteness to conclude that in every transitive model that $X$ is a member, $X$ is stationary.